# Plotly: How to assign background colors to different ranges in a radar or polar chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to change the background color of a radar chart in a way, that different value ranges get different colors, e.g. a radar chart with a range from 1-5, where 1-3 gets a red background color and 3-5 gets a green background color.
There is a possibility to change the color, but only for the whole circle.

Do you have any ideas?

EDIT

This is the sample code that I've used with the only possibilities that I've found to add colors.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

categories = ['processing cost','mechanical properties','chemical stability',
              'thermal stability', 'device integration']

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=[1, 5, 2, 2, 3],
      theta=categories,
      fill='toself',
      name='Product A'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=[4, 3, 2.5, 1, 2],
      theta=categories,
      fill='toself',
      name='Product B'
))

fig.update_layout(
  paper_bgcolor="red",
  polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(
      color="red",
      visible=True,
      range=[0, 5]
    )),
  showlegend=False
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Could you share your coding attempts?

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Comment: I have basically the example from here: https://plot.ly/python/radar-chart/#multiple-trace-radar-chart
I added the background color in the update_layout function

Comment: @Bene_91 Your snippet  raises an error at `showlegend=False`

Comment: @vestland you're right, it raises an error. But I get the error from `bgcolor="red"`. I'll update the code above.

Comment: As far as I've seen, I can only update the color of the radial axis and only the outermost circle (angularaxis).

Comment: @Bene_91 I've got a suggestion coming up shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to specify different background colors for different parts of the plot. But I if I understand correctly what you're aiming for here, you can do so with the correct combination of some `go.Barpolar()` and `go.Scatterpolar()` traces:

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# categories:
categories = ['processing cost','mechanical properties','chemical stability',
              'thermal stability', 'device integration']

# values:
rVars1=[1, 5, 2, 2, 3]
rVars2=[4, 3, 2.5, 1, 2]

# colors
values = [3,5]
colors = ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8)']

# some calcultations to place all elements
slices=len(rVars1)
fields=[max(rVars1)]*slices
circle_split = [360/slices]*(slices)
theta= 0
thetas=[0]
for t in circle_split:
    theta=theta+t
    thetas.append(theta)
thetas

# plotly 
fig = go.Figure()

# "background"
for t in range(0, len(colors)):
    fig.add_trace(go.Barpolar(
        r=[values[t]],
        width=360,
        marker_color=[colors[t]],
        opacity=0.6,
        name = 'Range ' + str(t+1)
        #showlegend=False,
    ))
    t=t+1

# trace 1
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
       text = categories,
        r = rVars1,
        mode = 'lines+text+markers',
        fill='toself',
        fillcolor='rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4)',
        textposition='bottom center',
        marker = dict(color = 'blue'),
        name = 'Product A'))

# adjust layout
fig.update_layout(
    template=None,
    polar = dict(radialaxis = dict(gridwidth=0.5,
                               range=[0, max(fields)], 
                              showticklabels=True, ticks='', gridcolor = "grey"),
                 angularaxis = dict(showticklabels=False, ticks='',
                               rotation=45,
                               direction = "clockwise",
                               gridcolor = "white")))

fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='white')
fig.show()
```

**Edit: Multiple traces**

Your sample code covers multiple traces. And that would quickly turn into a fine mess with my initial approach. Below is a snippet that covers multiple traces. To make this look good, I've put the category names at the edge of the circle in it's own trace with various text positions to make the names fall on the outside of the circle. Then I'm adding a single trace for each Product A and B. I hope this will be useful.

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# categories:
categories = ['processing cost','mechanical properties','chemical stability',
              'thermal stability', 'device integration']

# values:
rVars1=[1, 5, 2, 2, 3]
rVars2=[4, 3, 2.5, 1, 2]

rAllMax = max(rVars1+rVars2)

# colors
values = [3,5]
colors = ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9)', ]

# some calcultations to place all elements
slices=len(rVars1)
fields=[max(rVars1)]*slices
circle_split = [360/slices]*(slices)
theta= 0
thetas=[0]
for t in circle_split:
    theta=theta+t
    thetas.append(theta)
thetas

# set up label positions
df_theta=pd.DataFrame({'theta':thetas, 'positions':['middle right', 'middle right',
                                                    'bottom center', 'middle left',
                                                    'middle left', 'middle left']})


# plotly 
fig = go.Figure()

# "background"
for t in range(0, len(colors)):
    fig.add_trace(go.Barpolar(
        r=[values[t]],
        width=360,
        marker_color=[colors[t]],
        opacity=0.6,
        name = 'Range ' + str(t+1)
        #showlegend=False,
    ))
    t=t+1

for r, cat in enumerate(categories):
    #print(r, cat)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
            text = cat,
            r = [rAllMax],
            theta = [thetas[r]],
            mode = 'lines+text+markers',
            fill='toself',
            fillcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)',
            line = dict(color='black'),
            #textposition='bottom center',
            textposition=df_theta[df_theta['theta']==thetas[r]]['positions'].values[0],
            marker = dict(line_color='white', color = 'black'),
            marker_symbol ='circle',
            name = cat,
            showlegend = False))



# trace 1
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
        #text = categories,
        r = rVars1,
        mode = 'lines+text+markers',
        fill='toself',
        fillcolor='rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4)',
        textposition='bottom center',
        marker = dict(color = 'blue'),
        marker_symbol ='square',
        name = 'Product A'))

# trace 2
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
        #text = categories,
        r = rVars2,
        mode = 'lines+text+markers',
        fill='toself',
        fillcolor='rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4)',
        textposition='bottom center',
        marker = dict(color = 'Green'),
        name = 'Product B'))


# adjust layout
fig.update_layout(
    template=None,
    polar = dict(radialaxis = dict(gridwidth=0.5,
                               range=[0, max(fields)], 
                              showticklabels=True, ticks='', gridcolor = "grey"),
                 angularaxis = dict(showticklabels=False, ticks='',
                               rotation=45,
                               direction = "clockwise",
                               gridcolor = "white")))

fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='white')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice idea! That's what I was looking for.